# How to fit image inside the bounds of a parent container in React Native Expo

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I have been trying to fit a logo image into a parent container for a login page. This is the format for the page:

```
<NativeBaseProvider>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoBox}> 
                    {/* <Image source={images.logo} style={styles.logo} alt="Company Logo"  /> */}
                    {/* <NativeBaseProvider> */}
                                    <Image  
                                        source={ images.logo }
                                        alt="Company Logo" 
                                        style={styles.logo}
                                    />
                    {/* </NativeBaseProvider> */}
                </View>
                ... rest of login page stuff
</NativeBaseProvider>
```

```
container: {
        flex: 1,
        // width: '100%',
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
},
logoBox: {
        // height: '100%',
        height: 300,
        width: '80%',
        // maxWidth: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        // padding: SIZES.medium,
        marginBottom: 60,
},
logo: {
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        flex: 1,
        // maxWidth: '100%',
        // objectFit: 'contain',
},
```

The issue that I am having is that the image is a pretty large image. I am able to make it fit in the logoBox parent container when I am in web view. But when I check how it looks on the mobile app view, it is spilling off of the screen on the sides.

I have tried to use various combinations of maxWidth, objectFit, width, and height values, as seen in the commented out code, but I can't seem to find something that allows for the code to fit universally on both web and mobile views.

Comment: Try adding the prop resizeMode="contain"  to the image

Comment: Also add a width or a height to the image style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set resizeMode to stretch and give height and width to 100% or flex 1

you can read about resizeMode here https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode

```html
<NativeBaseProvider>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoBox}> 
                    {/* <Image source={images.logo} style={styles.logo} alt="Company Logo"  /> */}
                    {/* <NativeBaseProvider> */}
                                    <Image  
                                        source={ images.logo }
                                        alt="Company Logo" 
                                        style={styles.logo}
                                        resizeMode="contain" // or set to stretch or cover 
                                    />
                    {/* </NativeBaseProvider> */}
                </View>
                ... rest of login page stuff
</NativeBaseProvider>
```

Comment: I set flex: 1 and deleted width and height in my logo style. resizeMode is already set to contain in logo as well. This didn't change the way the logo is displayed.

Comment: you are passing resize mode as a style pass it as a prop

Comment: @onomatopoeia_truck were you able to fix this image issue ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes I was able to fix it using resizeMode: 'contain', flex: 1, maxWidth: 80%' in logo.